# javascript: reading id3 tags from mp3 stream

Tags: javascript, stream, mp3, id3

I'm writing a Webradio Player for Firefox OS (mobilephone OS based on webstandards). Now I want to add a feature, that displays for example the actual Title like some radiostations are sending and VLC-Mediaplayer for example is able to display. All tested streams are using MP3. I'm playing the audio via the html-audio-tag. Until now i've tested https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader and http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript. The JavaScript-ID3-Reader seams not to be able to handle streams. The other way doesn't writes an log via "console.log(title);". Does anybody know a way to add this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that it is impossible this way. But there is a much easier way:

```
var meta = document.getElementById("audio").mozGetMetadata();
```

The id audio refers to a audio tag. You can acces the title by `meta.title`. But there is a bug in firefox (firefox os, too) that causes that this isn't working with mp3-streams: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=908902